# How can optimize XSL Stylesheet generation and transformation

Tags: xslt

I am generating stylesheet from word document.xml which contains table having placeholders.

Each row of table has same style, same chunk of elements(tags) being repeated in XSL stylesheet that causes XSL file to be large.

Is there any way to specify same style of row to all rows of table without repeating style for each row ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Following is a single row containing placeholders, this row will be repeated for each record along with style information. I want style to be separate but have reference from each row to that style.

---

### Document.xml

```
  <w:tr w:rsidR="00136F0A" w:rsidRPr="00DD43C2" w:rsidTr="00455F4A">
    <w:trPr>
      <w:cnfStyle w:val="000000100000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="1" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/>
      <w:trHeight w:val="79"/>
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:cnfStyle w:val="001000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/>
        <w:tcW w:w="2304" w:type="dxa"/>
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00136F0A" w:rsidRPr="00DD43C2" w:rsidRDefault="0032158A" w:rsidP="009F4FBF">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> MERGEFIELD  JointName  \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:noProof/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>«JointName»</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="2016" w:type="dxa"/>
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00136F0A" w:rsidRPr="00DD43C2" w:rsidRDefault="0032158A" w:rsidP="009F4FBF">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:cnfStyle w:val="000000100000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="1" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> MERGEFIELD  X  \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:noProof/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>«X»</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="2016" w:type="dxa"/>
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00136F0A" w:rsidRPr="00DD43C2" w:rsidRDefault="0032158A" w:rsidP="009F4FBF">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:cnfStyle w:val="000000100000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="1" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> MERGEFIELD  Y  \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:noProof/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>«Y»</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="2019" w:type="dxa"/>
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00136F0A" w:rsidRPr="00DD43C2" w:rsidRDefault="0032158A" w:rsidP="009F4FBF">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:cnfStyle w:val="000000100000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="1" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> MERGEFIELD  Z  \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:noProof/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>«Z»</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="2016" w:type="dxa"/>
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00136F0A" w:rsidRPr="00DD43C2" w:rsidRDefault="0032158A" w:rsidP="009F4FBF">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:cnfStyle w:val="000000100000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="1" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> MERGEFIELD  Fixity </w:instrText>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:noProof/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>«Fixity»</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Narrow" w:hAnsi="Arial Narrow" w:cs="Arial"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_MtoLjRNFNNLWdNb1Y2VTBLNFE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_MtoLjRNFNNYjVZR2dKcGtDLTQ/edit?usp=sharing